# make a flutter app in which the launch icon is working as a link

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I was wondering if it is possible to make a Flutter app and when the user hits the launch icon, the browser opens with a specific URL. I know that you can make shortcuts on your phone home screen with the URL you want but I was wondering if it is possible as an Android app. So the app should do almost nothing just when I tap on it the browser should open..

is this possible? and is yes how should I think it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be possible using the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package. You need to execute the code in the main function.

In main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {

  Future<String> _launchURL() async {
    const url = 'https://www.google.com';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
      return 'text';
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<String>(
          future: _launchURL(), // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            return Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => _launchURL(),
                    child: Text('Hello'))
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Well thank you for your reply but unfortunately, this code didn't work 

I got this error 

"If you're running a test, you can call the `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` as the first line in your test's `main()` method to initialize the binding."

Kind regards

Comment: I updated the answer with the complete code example

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer, Worked like a charm. 
Have a great day! 
Best regards,

Comment: If you can please mark the answer as the accepted one.